# How do you construct barriers for minimal surfaces?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, minimal-surfaces, maximum-principle

There is no comparison principle for minimal surfaces: two minimal surfaces $M_1, M_2 \subset B$ in the unit ball of $\mathbf{R}^3$, with the boundary $\partial M_1 \subset \partial B$ lying 'above' $\partial M_2$, can intersect in the interior. (This is in contrast with *area-minimizing* surfaces, for whom this is impossible.)

> My question is: what tools are available to work around this issue when trying to construct barriers for minimal surfaces that are *not* minimizing?

This question is a bit open-ended, so let me give a specific problem that I could not solve due to (I believe) this failure of the comparison principle.

*Example.* Let $C \subset B_R$ be the standard catenoid, considered in a ball large enough that $C$ is *not* minimizing. Then every minimal surface $M \subset B_R$ with boundary $\partial M \subset \partial B_R$ lying above $C \cap \partial B_R$ has a 'thicker neck' than $C$: $M \cap \{ z = 0 \} \not \subset \{ x^2 + y^2 < 1 \}$.

Comment: It's impossible to answer such a vague question, but if I understood your more concrete example correctly you can show that a surface with boundary "above" that of the catenoid can't lie on one side of the catenoid and be connected by considering the family of blowdowns of the catenoid intersected with the ball the geometry of the catenoid means these all have boundary below the reference piece of the catenoid.  The connectedness of $M$  means the family eventually hits $M$ which violates the maximum principle.

Comment: @RBega2 That's nice - thanks! You're right that the question is vague. I had trouble coming up with a more specific formulation. I guess I was hoping for answers or comments of the form such as 'You can try doing A or B'. I guess the general principle along what you're suggesting to solve the example might be something like 'Try to find deformations of the surfaces to apply a strong maximum principle.'?

Comment: Sure why not. In general I think these things are usually more ad hoc and coming from the geometry of the specific situation rather than coming from any general method.  It's why geometric analysis is a more interesting subject than most in my (probably unpopular) opinion.

Comment: @RBega2 Could you give me some examples of papers where they have to come up with one of those ad hoc workarounds? I'm really just trying to find some inspiration...

Comment: "The strong halfspace theorem for minimal surfaces" by Hoffman and Meeks.

Comment: @RBega2 Dang, that's a very nice paper, but it's one I'm already familiar with! Anyway, I'll stop moving the goalposts - if you want to post your comments as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Just to add a bit to @RBega2 's comment (which I think is spot on), the way to get a barrier argument in such situations is to have a *foliation* of a region by barriers. Then you can move until you make one-sided contact. I guess that in your specific situation, if you know the convex hulls of the boundaries are disjoint then you can conclude the minimal surfaces are disjoint (note that this is precisely this barrier argument using foliations by planes!).

Comment: @OtisChodosh Hm, I'm not sure I understood your comment. The blowdowns of the catenoid that RBega2 used in his comment intersect one another, so they're not a foliation. In fact, if you had a foliation of a region (say, one side of a minimal surface) by barriers, wouldn't the minimal surface be stable? This would make it hard to apply for surfaces that have a Morse index. For the second point, I agree - if the convex hulls of the boundaries are disjoint, then by the convex hull property the interiors must be too. However, to me this seems extremely unlikely to hold in real-life examples [...]

Comment: [...] where one is trying to show that two minimal surfaces are disjoint. For example, it fails for the neck example with the catenoid I give in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I guess you don't need that they are disjoint, just that you can move them "in towards the barrier" to get one-sided touching.

Comment: @OtisChodosh My bad, I guess I read that too literally. I appreciate your comments, thanks!